# "set -e" in shell and command substitution

Tags: shell, robustness

In shell scripts `set -e` is often used to make them more robust by stopping the script when some of the commands executed from the script exits with non-zero exit code.

It's usually easy to specify that you don't care about some of the commands succeeding by adding `|| true` at the end.

The problem appears when you actually care about the return value, but don't want the script to stop on non-zero return code, for example:

```
output=$(possibly-failing-command)
if [ 0 == $? -a -n "$output" ]; then
  ...
else
  ...
fi
```

Here we want to both check the exit code (thus we can't use `|| true` inside of command substitution expression) and get the output. However, if the command in command substitution fails, the whole script stops due to `set -e`.

Is there a clean way to prevent the script from stopping here without unsetting `-e` and setting it back afterwards?

Comment: What is wrong with unsetting -e?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, inline the process substitution in the if-statement

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

if ! output=$(possibly-failing-command); then
  ...
else
  ...
fi
```

#### Command Fails

```
$ ( set -e; if ! output=$(ls -l blah); then echo "command failed"; else echo "output is -->$output<--"; fi )
/bin/ls: cannot access blah: No such file or directory
command failed
```

#### Command Works

```
$ ( set -e; if ! output=$(ls -l core); then echo "command failed"; else echo "output is: $output"; fi )
output is: -rw------- 1 siegex users 139264 2010-12-01 02:02 core
```

Comment: thanks, that works! For some reason though I get `ls: blah: No such file or directory` message twice. Any ideas why?

Comment: I just took your example which does `ls -l blah`, and it showed the message twice

Comment: @ivant hmm, I really can't say why that's happening.  Out of curiosity, is the 2nd one prefixed with `output is:`?  Does this happen if you change `blah` to something crazy like `as9dfasdf0afd` ?

Comment: It doesn't matter, what it is, as long as the file does not exist. I actually found the reason though: it prints it twice under `zsh`, once under `bash`.

Comment: @ivant that's very interesting. Not quite sure what would be causing `zsh` to behave that way. Good to note though

Comment: Tried in zsh, it is printed only once.

Comment: Besides `if`, one can also make up a test for `$?` after a `||` like: `foo="$(bar)" || [ 3 -eq $? ]`